# XmlPullParser self closed tag loop

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I need to make loop for xml tags. Example on android tutorial page isn't for me, I need make loop through self closed tag eg. `<foo data="exmample" />`, unfortunately one exaple of XmlPullParser loop is with `XmlPullParser.END_TAG` but this doesn't work beacause my example doesn't have `</foo>`

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the same. There will be `END_TAG` event for a `<foo/>` tag same as for a `<foo> ... </foo>` tag

You get attributes at the `START_TAG` event.

Comment: Indeed! My problem was with `parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "foo");` this fragment is unnecessary in my case. Thanks!